# Sort & order data in Plotly Python

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, google-colaboratory, plotly-python

I want to sort data in plotly (`group` bar chart), have 3 columns & some `NaN` in their rows. want to plot as **descending** according to the highest value of every column (having the highest value in all 3 columns)...
also I tried the code below but then I realized that was silly because it just sorted the columns, so the first name got the highest value.

```py
bar_plots = [
  go.Bar(x=x, y=plAll['col1'].sort_values(ascending=False), name='col1', marker=go.bar.Marker(color='#0343df')),
  go.Bar(x=x, y=plAll['col2'].sort_values(ascending=False), name='col2', marker=go.bar.Marker(color='#e50000')),
  go.Bar(x=x, y=plAll['col3'].sort_values(ascending=False), name='col3', marker=go.bar.Marker(color='#BEA797'))

fig = go.Figure(data=bar_plots, layout=layout)
]
```

as you can see in the image, one of the values in the third group is higher than the second group but it didn't sort correctly.
this image is done by sorting the DataFrame itself! wanna the exact code in Plotly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's working to me :)

```
plAll = pd.DataFrame({"first": [0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2], "second": [7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3],
                      "third": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2]})
x = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
bar_plots = [
    go.Bar(x=x, y=plAll['first'].sort_values(ascending=True), name='col1', marker=go.bar.Marker(color='#0343df')),
    go.Bar(x=x, y=plAll['second'].sort_values(ascending=False), name='col2', marker=go.bar.Marker(color='#e50000')),
    go.Bar(x=x, y=plAll['third'].sort_values(ascending=False), name='col3', marker=go.bar.Marker(color='#BEA797'))
]
fig = go.Figure(data=bar_plots)
fig.show()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5hwW.png)

Here is a nice article about group bar charts in plotly!

https://medium.com/@moritzkoerber/how-to-plot-a-grouped-stacked-bar-chart-in-plotly-df1685b83460

Comment: thanks but the data you've made looks independent (so the highest value comes to the first column), my x-axis is dependent & when I do that, it shows the wrong value for that column.